# how can I add modal to navbar in yii2?

Tags: yii2, modal-dialog, navbar

I'm trying to add a modal to my navbar.
This is my \views\project_form.php:

```
<?php Modal::begin(['id' => 'modal', ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'Wert')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

and this is my Controller:

```
function actionShowmodal(){
    $js='$("#modal").modal("show")';
    $this->getView()->registerJs($js);      
    return $this->render('create');
}
```

I did this as it was described here [how can I add modal to navbar in yii2 using yii2 -bootstrap extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601352/how-can-i-add-modal-to-navbar-in-yii2-using-yii2-bootstrap-extension?rq=1).
When I use a modal navbar in my index.php it works. But when I use a modal navbar in my form, an error is issued: Undefined variable: model.
How can I fix it?

Comment: In your output code, there is the js? It is under the definition of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a form in modal you need to pass the respective model for the form

```
function actionShowmodal(){
 $model = new RespectiveModel(); //Model For the Form
 $js='$("#modal").modal("show")';
 $this->getView()->registerJs($js);      
 return $this->render('create',["model"=>$model]);
}
```

and in your "create.php" view file where you are rendering the form, pass the model variable again

```
echo $this->render('project_form',["model"=>$model]);
```

Comment: I modified my controller as you wrote it and now it works!  Thank You!!!